# how to upload files to amzon s3 through form data?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I am trying to upload my files to my Amazon S3 bucket. In my research I got this link which worked fine and the files got uploaded:

https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/aws/express_multer_s3

But I need to concatenate this to my web services which the request will have the Json form data, so I have tried this:

```
aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'mysecretkey',
    accessKeyId: 'my access key',

     });
    s3 = new aws.S3();

           /**multer function*/

           var transfer = multerS3({
              s3: s3,
              bucket: 'mu_bucket_name',

              key: function (req, file, cb) {
                  console.log("cb");

                  var newFileName = Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname;
                  var fullPath = 'path/'+ newFileName;

                  cb(null, fullPath); //use Date.now() for unique file keys
                  console.log(fullPath);
                  console.log("I am getting till this console")
              }
           });


              var upload = multer({storage:transfer}).any();

               upload(req,res, function (err,res) {
                  console.log("req");
                console.log(err);
                console.log(res);
               })
```

Above is my code and I am getting no response in:

```
 upload(req,res, function (err,res) {
                  console.log("req");
                console.log(err);
                console.log(res);
               })
```

But I am getting the:

```
console.log(fullPath);
```

as:

```
'path/1499786601509-S.mp4'
```

Any help?
I am not getting any response and file is not getting uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work if not make sure all your configurations are given correct to the aws config, if your config are correct then also the above code doesn't work then try to reinstall the aws npm modules.